# Execute dynamic sql and pl/sql in Java via web interface

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

Currently I'm making sort of SQL command line interface for web-based application. It should act roughly like sqlPlus.
I have encountered a problem how to execute sql's. They can be both as SQL and/or PL/SQL.

First way I thought that I can split them (by ';' or ';/') and detect separately if it's sql select or delete/update/insert or pl/sql.

Now I cant find for PL/SQL Backus–Naur Form to make regexp. May be there exists easier way?

Generally, What is the best way to make such logic ?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) which have a [PLSQL grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1209225566284/PLSQL3.g). You can generate code for java and  [other languages](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Code+Generation+Targets).

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp to separate SQL statement and PLSQL in a sql script is almost impossible.

```
declare
begin
select sysdate from dual;

dbms.output('hello');
end;
/
```

Do you have any ideas how to recognize such a simple PLSQL code using regexp. [A SQL Parser](http://sqlparser.com/index.php) is what you need to achieve this,  here is [an article](http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/separate-the-sql-commands-in-a-sql-script/) that may helpful.